# how to resume a screen session?

Tags: ssh, debian, gnu-screen

When I log to my SSH, I have 2 screen sessions:

```
screen -list
There are screens on:
        4278.chat       (07/16/15 14:26:47)     (Attached)
        15127.notifier  (07/16/15 13:27:57)     (Detached)
2 Sockets
```

I try to resume the chat screen:

```
screen -r chat
There is a screen on:
        4278.chat       (07/16/15 14:26:47)     (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching chat.
```

How can I resume the 'chat' screen ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it's still attached. Meaning you can't reattach with -r. Try -x instead. This should work. With -x, you have multiple parties attached to the same screen

Edit 1
You can also remotely detach a screen with -D. Or combine it with -D -r. Force it with -D -R. Or even do everything your possible by saying -D -RR.

-x only allows you to use this screen with other together. I use this for my home network, when I am too lazy to turn around to the other keyboard to type something in.

Here, have a look at the manual. It describes it fairly well:
[man screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)